# silvio packer for shared libray leads to error: "ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned"

Tags: elf, x86-64, packers, gcc, software-security

I'm trying to implement a packer based on silvio infection. The packer works fine for ET_EXEC. However, it failed with "ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned" error for the shared library.

Questions

1. what does "ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned" mean ?
2. is silvio infection only works for ET_EXEC ?

silvio infection

1. [Learning Linux Binary Analysis](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=42pLDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=silvio%20infection%20elf&source=bl&ots=_xUO75dho3&sig=ACfU3U1YO1GXp90fkUhjc6rzaQseV3Fkaw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjy-cXDuZT1AhUZHXAKHaCOATkQ6AF6BAgcEAM#v=onepage&q=silvio%20infection%20elf&f=false)
2. https://github.com/youben11/silvio-text-infect